# Shiny Rhandsontable - Renderer - Use color from factor (Pallete)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a dataset which I have created a column with color codes based on another column.

```
 colourCount = length(unique(Desc.File$VARIABLECODE))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))
Colors <- getPalette(colourCount) 

Desc.File$ColorCode <- factor(Desc.File$VARIABLECODE, labels = Colors)
```

The object created is then a list of HEX color codes

> "#E41A1C" "#D42229" "#C52B37" "#B63445" "#A73D52" "#974560" "#884E6E" "#79577C" "#6A6089" "#5B6997"
>    "#4B71A5" "#3C7AB2" "#3880B1" "#3A85A8" "#3C899E" "#3E8D94" "#3F918B" "#419681" "#439A77" "#459E6E"
>    "#47A364" "#49A75A"

With this column I am sourcing the colors to a plot and I would also like to use the same colors on the background/text color on the Rhandsontable.

```
color_renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

clr   = instance.params.ColorCode

td.style.background=  hex(clr[row])
}
"

colnames(Summary.tab) <- c("Code", "Brand", "Type", "Description", "Metric", "ColorCode", "Execution", "Cost")
Summary.tab <- data.frame(Check=rep(TRUE, n),Summary.tab)
DT = rhandsontable(Summary.tab, readOnly = FALSE, rowHeaders= NULL, useTypes= TRUE, selectCallback = TRUE) %>% hot_col("Code", renderer=color_renderer)
```

Im trying to use the renderer to take the colors from the color column in my dataset and then use it as the background color, but it doesnt work. (I never coded on JS before so I dont know what Im doing)

Please help :)

Comment: Someone? :( I need to solve this thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter `ColorCode` to a rhansontable, only then you can pick it up in renderer function. Here is the example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

color_renderer = "
    function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
        if (instance.params) {
            clr = instance.params.ColorCode
            clr = clr instanceof Array ? clr : [clr]
            td.style.background =  clr[row]
        }

    }"

set.seed(12345)
Desc.File <- data.frame(VARIABLECODE = sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE))

colourCount <- length(unique(Desc.File$VARIABLECODE))
getPalette <- colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))
colors <- getPalette(colourCount) 

Desc.File$ColorCode <- factor(Desc.File$VARIABLECODE, labels = colors)


ui <- fluidPage(
    rHandsontableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(Desc.File, ColorCode = Desc.File$ColorCode) %>% 
            hot_cols(renderer = color_renderer)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```